# Как указать для xml, xsd схему, которая находится в интернете?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd

Есть xml файл, а также ссылка на xsd файл. Как его подключить к xml?

```
<product name="qwerty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceLocation="product.xsd">
```

Есть ссылка на product.xsd, можно ли как то сделать то же самое, только вместо product.xsd была бы ссылка?

Comment: Ссылка в виде `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/product.xsd`, так что-ли?

Comment: @Streletz Нет, смысл в том, что бы xsd бралась с моего сайта. Как то так:  (http://www.myOwnSite.ru/product.xsd)